# Spring Cache doesn't ignore Null key even I set the condition

Tags: spring, caching

In my application, the cache key is *nullable*, so I just wanna put it in cache when the key **is not null**.

I've tried a lot of different ways but it looks like *Spring Cache* always want a none empty key. Otherwise it throws Exception:

> IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe
>   you are using named params on classes without debug info?)
>   Builder[public com.madme.sharding.model.App
>   com.madme.sharding.service.impl.AppServiceImpl.saveOrUpdateApp(com.madme.sharding.model.App)]
>   caches=[appsCache] | key='#result.uuid' | keyGenerator='' |
>   cacheManager='redisCacheManager' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' |
>   unless='#p0.uuid == null' Ref: 1490185514616_gcfal96

I thought if I specified 'unless' condition like below, it should just ignore this *CachePut* without throwing any exceptions.

```
// I've tried #result.uuid and #p0.uuid, same output
@CachePut(value = APPS_CACHE, cacheManager = "redisCacheManager", key = "#result.uuid", unless = "#result.uuid == null")
public App saveOrUpdateApp(App app) {
    return appRepository.saveAndFlush(app);
}
```

Any one has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you check th result value and not the parameter value? So `#result.uuid == null` instead of `#p0.uuid == null`...

Comment: I tried both. Same issue. In fact result.uuid equals to p0.uuid because uuid is just a property

Comment: Instead of `unless` try `condition="#p0.uuid != null"`

Comment: 'condition' worked... Didn't recognize that the blacklist ('unless') and whitelist ('condition') aren't checked at the same time. 'condition' is applied before key generation while 'unless' is applied after. Thank you v much @M. Deinum

Answer (score 3):

'condition="#p0.uuid != null"' worked... Didn't recognize that the blacklist ('unless') and whitelist ('condition') aren't checked at the same time. 'condition' is applied before key generation while 'unless' is applied after. Thank you v much @M.Deinum